# A subgroup of a cyclic normal subgroup of a Group is Normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that Subgroup of a Cyclic Normal subgroup of a Group is again Normal ? If so any hints for the proof?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. It follows from a more general fact: a [characteristic subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup) of a normal subgroup of $G$ is also a normal subgroup of $G$. It's even easier to think about the question in these general terms.

Answer (score 2):

If $H<N\lhd G$ and $N$ is cyclic, then $H$ is a *characteristic* subgroup of $N$, i.e. it is left invariant by *all* automorphism of $N$, thus including those outer automorphisms of $N$ that are actually inner automorhisms of $G$, i.e. $H$ is conjugation invariant.

Comment: But how do we prove $H$ is a _characteristic subgroup_ of $N$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is one of the several cases when normality is transitive. If

$$N\triangleleft C\triangleleft G\,\,\,,\,\,C=\text{cyclic, then}\;\; C=\langle c\rangle\Longrightarrow N=\langle c^k\rangle\Longrightarrow$$

$$\Longrightarrow \,\,\forall g\in G\,\,,\,\,x^{-1}c^{rk}x=(x^{-1}c^kx)^r\in N\,....$$

Comment: How can we say that $x^{-1}c^kx \in N$ ?

Comment: I believe it would have been clearer to use $(x^{-1}c^rx)^k \in N $ in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is the group and $N = \langle x \rangle $ is a cyclic normal subgroup of $G$.

Note that for different values of $k$, $H_k= \langle x^{gcd(k,o(x)} \rangle$ are subgroups of $N$.

### Step 1:

$N$ is normal $\Rightarrow$ $\forall g \in G:\ gxg^{-1} \in N$ $\Rightarrow$ For all $g \in G$, there exist $\alpha$ (namely $\alpha_g$) such that $gxg^{-1}=x^{\alpha_g}$.

### Step 2:

Now, I claim $\forall g \in G, \forall y\in N:\ gy=y^{\alpha_g}g$

Proof:

Since $y \in N$, there exists $l$ such that $y=x^l$.

$\forall g \in G:\ gy=gx^l=gxx^{l-1}=x^{\alpha_g}gx^{l-1}=x^{\alpha_g}gxx^{l-2}=x^{2\alpha_g}gx^{l-2}= \cdots = x^{l\alpha_g}g=y^{\alpha_g}g$.

### Step 3:

$\forall g \in G, \forall y\in H_k:\ gy=y^{\alpha_g}g$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall g \in G, \forall y\in H_k:\ gyg^{-1}=y^{\alpha_g}$

Since $y\in H_k$, $y^{\alpha_g}\in H_k$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall g \in G: gH_kg^{-1} \subset H_k$

Consequently $H_k$ are normal in $G$.

Comment: Please *do not* post duplicate answers.  If one answer adequately addresses two different questions, please only answer *one* question (generally, choose to answer the higher quality question, and if the quality is similar, answer the older question), and flag the other question as a duplicate.